# ith term in a series after m operations where a operation is ith term = ith term+(i-1)th term

Tags: sequences-and-series

series of n numbers is given

```
A operation is performed by:
    for i = 2 to N:
        Ai = Ai + A(i-1)
```

our task is to find the xth element of the array (i.e., Ax) after performing the above operation M times.

How could we generalized to find the ith term.
My approcah is

```
ith(mth opeartion)= ith term(m-1th opeartion) + (i-1)th term(mth operation)
```

But this is not possible as we are required the knowledge of the m-1 operation.
if m is large it is not possible.what is the generalized way to write the ith term

**Example**

```
let m = 3
let the series be 
1 2 3

Before the operations: [1, 2, 3]
After the first operation: [1, 3, 6]
After the second operation: [1, 4, 10]
After the third operation: [1, 5, 15]
```

So x(=3rd) th element will be 15

Comment: I have provided the example

Comment: please do wathc there are n terms

Comment: Just do it for 2-3 times and you get a sequence... check my answer below

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is taken from an ongoing contest:  https://www.codechef.com/FEB16/problems/STROPR

Comment: yes it is but the logic is mathematical.is it not allowed??

Answer (score 0):

After m times, the $A_i(new)$ will be 
$$A_i + mC_1 A_{i-1} + (m+1)C_2 A_{i-2} + ... (m+i-2)C_{i-1} A_{1} + (m+i-1)C_i A_{0}$$   Try it out for your example if you are doubtful

Comment: The writer is trying to cheat on a contest, https://www.codechef.com/FEB16/problems/STROPR .  The question should be closed.

Comment: okay I am closing this question.where should I close it??